# Docker History not showing FROM line?

Tags: docker, operating-system, containers

I'm trying to "reverse engineer" a docker image, and am using the `docker history` command. I'm expecting the output to have a "FROM:<base image>" name, but for some reason it will not appear for me.

I used the following commands:

1. ```
   docker pull ubuntu:latest
   ```
2. ```
   docker run ubuntu
   ```
3. ```
   docker history --no-trunc ubuntu
   ```

And I [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyO3x.png).

Unless I'm mistaken, there should be a FROM line at the top of the output, right? Since even in this case, the Dockerfile would have had `FROM scratch` as the first line. Anyone know what is causing this/what I can do to get the FROM line?

P.S. I'm trying to get "reverse engineer" a Docker Image into a Dockerfile so that I can find the Base image a given image was based on. If anyone has any other ideas/easier ways, I'm all ears too!

Comment: The Docker image history doesn't contain the name of the base image, it just embeds that image's layers.  The linked question matches the "P.S." real problem, and it includes a very detailed explanation of what's going on internally.